# Micro-controller drives solenoid 12 volt through interposing relay 5 volt issue

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, relay, solenoid

Purpose of attached circuit: driving a solenoid (cabinet lock) from microcontroller through relay with a 5 volt coil.

Components:

1. ATMEGA8
2. Relay 5 volt  with NO Contact
3. Solenoid 12 volt
4. power supply 12 volt
5. Regulator 7805 to generate 5 volts

[image]
[image]

Operation:

1. On state of controller pin: relay is energized and the contacts close and 12 volt feeds the solenoid and it is working well.
2. Off state of controller pin: relay is still energized and for sure the solenoid is still active. ( 3.9 volt is still there on the output pin of the controller.)
3. Off state of controller pin (in case the solenoid is disconnected from the circuit): relay is ee-energized, and it is working well as expected.

Note:

1. Logic in controller drives the output only.
2. The 7805 regulator is not mentioned in the above circuit.

   Can you help me to find the issue which leads the output of the controller to be forced to high when the solenoid is connected and the controller output should be low?

Comment: Is it a BJT where "Input from MC" is written ??

Comment: Plus the diode is in the wrong place. It should be across the coil.

Comment: @SadatRafi doide between termianl of coil (5)and ground(2)
i mean output from mc and input to interface circuit

Comment: This circuit totally wrong. Wait I'll give a diagram soon.

Comment: @Sadat: The OP's diode *is* across the coil and it's even the right way up. Have another look. OP is switching relay positive, not GND, and directly from the MCU (which may have been overloaded and the output is now stuck on high).

Comment: Ya transistor. The circuit has been drawn in a very unusual way. That's why I didn't understand it.

Comment: @Ahmedkamal can you show your microprocessor connections as well please?

Comment: @skvery i  added MC circuit as well

Comment: I get data on the G41A 5 V relay - 180 mA coil!  Please add the datasheet of your relay to the question as well please.

Comment: G5LA seems equivalent 5 V 72 mA coil.  The ATMEGA8A says "DC Current per I/O Pin ............................................... 40.0 mA"  You have destroyed that pin.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit should be like this.

[image]

[image]

These two are screenshots of the proteus simulation results. You have placed diode in the wrong position, plus haven't used a BJT / MOSFET. ATMEGA 8 can have a maximum 5.5 volts. I hope this will work.

Comment: thanks for your help ,the relay which connected to solenoid is 5 volt  why i need to add transistor ?

Comment: ATMEGA 8 can provide a maximum 40mA current per pin and 200mA per register. That's why you will need a transistor to increase the current. I prefer MOSFET over BJT.

Comment: His diode is in the same position @SadatRafi

Comment: He hasn’t used BJT.

Answer (score 0):

You need a transistor or mosfet to handle the relay current.

For me the simplest would be the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuVWxA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: if current of Solenoid is 600ma why i can't use  MOSFET direct to control the solenoid without relay in between.

Comment: Yes you can.  Just make sure that 600 mA is the peak and not the average current or link a datasheet in your question.  You can also then use nmos like VN10KM